# Ways of negating statements in Chinese

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking at negation in Chinese. I know:

不：我不去。I don't want to go.  不多：他话不多。He doesn't talk much.

没：他没去美国。He didn't go to America.

未：未必：not necessarily

否：不管我们喜欢与否，Whether we like it or not,

无：无处不有 everywhere

非：非常 unusual 非法 illegal

Are there other ways of negating in Chinese?

Comment: 不然 bkrs：① 不是这样：抄抄写写看起来很容易，其实不然。
② 用在对话开头，表示否定对方的话：不然，事情不像你说的那么简单。
③ 连词，表示如果不是上文所说的情况，就发生或可能发生下文所说的情况：快走吧，不然就要迟到了 | 明天我还有点事儿，不然倒可以陪你去一趟 | 他晚上不是读书，就是写点儿什么，再不然就是听听音乐。

Comment: Maybe one more: 禁止, 严禁 [forbidden, not allow] E.G. 我禁止你跟他有来往 [I (command you not)/(forbid you) to get interacted with him].

Answer (score 2):

A few more I can think of: 勿（勿忘我），莫（爱莫能助），毋（毋庸置疑），别 （别烦我）

Answer (score 2):

So far we have

> 不 (no), 不是(isn't)，不能 (unable)，不可(can't)，不得 (can't/not allow)，不許 (not allow)，不行 (can't)
>
> 否 (negative)
>
> 没 (didn't; had not)
>
> 未 (have not)
>
> 无 (without)
>
> 非 (is not)
>
> 勿, 莫, 毋, 别 (don't)

I can think of one more

休(give up/ **don't**): 休要 (don't); 休想 (don't hope to/ don't think about);休得無禮 (don't be rude)

Also:

*難 (difficult): as an adverb virtually means 'can't'*

*e.g. 難敵 (can't win against); 難忘 (can't forget)*